# Render Symfony form field multiple time inside loop

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a simple formType with an single `checkBoxType`

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('domain_choose', CheckboxType::class, [
        'label' => false,
    ]);
}
```

Then I render it inside a loop

```
{% for domain, availability in availabilities %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_widget(form.domain_choose) }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that, only the first checkbox of the loop is rendered.

I tried to manually change the form name without succes

```
{'full_name': 'domain_choose[domain_choose_' ~ loop.index ~ ']'},
```

Is there a way to render this checkbox multiple time inside my loop ? Or should  I use a single checkbox input without formType ?

Answer (score 0):

**@Jérôme** As per symfony form you do not repeat form element. If you need multiple checkbox then you can  use something like this

```
$builder->add('domain_choose', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices'  => array(
        'Select' => null,
        'Domain1' => 'Domain1',
        'Domain2' => 'Domain2',
    ),
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true
));
```

expanded => true and multiple => true is used for (multiple)checkbox, For more detail you can visit http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html